# Symfony 5 Select a city autocomplete for user registration

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, symfony5

i have all City list on my Database and i would like my users to choose their city when registering the list is long and the page load too

On my FormType i have this :

```
            ->add('city', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => City::class,
       ])
```

And this for get the City as JsonResponse :

```
/**
 * @Route("/citySearch/{_query?}", name="handle_search", methods={"POST", "GET"})
 */
public function handleSearchRequest(Request $request, $_query)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    if ($_query)
    {
        $data = $em->getRepository(City::class)->findByCiTy($_query);
    }

    $resultlist = [];
    foreach ($data as $d){
        array_push($resultlist, $d->getNom());
    }

    $resultlist = [];
    foreach ($data as $d){
        array_push($resultlist, $d->getNom());
    }

    $list[] = [
        'options' => $resultlist,
    ];

    return new JsonResponse($list);
}
```

What will be the most optimized and fastest way for the user to choose his city please?

Answer (score 0):

you can use pagination lib for return in small quantities exemple link:

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/tutorials/pagination.html

or you can use views in database

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

Comment: Thank you, but my goal is to pre-enter the name of the city when registering is to choose the line